# How to keep white-space's width at normal single character

Tags: html, css, markdown, jekyll

I made a blog post using a code block.  In the code, I used 2 `white-spaces` indent.  But the indent size of the code block looks like one white-space, because a single white-space looks about half size of other ordinary character.

How can I keep `white-space`'s width at a normal single character?

I'm using jekyll.

Comment: Use width, padding, or margins, not white space.

Comment: Show your code and explain what you really want. Two consecutive spaces collapse into one in normal rendering. Maybe you just need to prevent that.

Comment: I'm so sorry to have asked an ambiguous question. 
I made a source code example on my blog. But the indentation wasn't what I expected. My indentation rule is 2 white-spaces. But It looked like 1 white space.
Fortunately, my question was solved by @SamuelLiew answer.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a monospace font like:

```
"Courier New", Courier, monospace

"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace
```

What StackOverflow is using for code blocks:

```
Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif
```